# Как установить Lua-модуль в nginx 1.15.*?

Tags: nginx, debian, vds

установил из коробки nginx-extras, но проблема в том, что с ним сразу идет nginx 1.10.*, мне бы очень сильно хотелось установить nginx 1.15.* и Lua-модуль к нему же. Как это возможно? И возможно ли вообще?
ОС: Linux, Debian 9 Stretch

Comment: 1.14 не устроит? https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nginx-extras

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, это возможно, однако, учтите, что по состоянию на момент ответа модуль ещё не был протестирован на совместимость с nginx 1.15, поэтому при сборке могут потребоваться какие-либо изменения в его исходный код.

Вам потребуются [исходники nginx](https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.15.3.tar.gz), окружение для сборки (`apt-get install build-essential`, а также зависимости, перечисленные в документации к серверу и модулю) и [собственно модуль](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module).

Процесс сборки модуля описан в [его документации](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#readme).